# interacting with multiple controller zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

I already developed with ZF1, now I'm playing with ZF2. I have already working the Album application when you follow the tutorial, and everything works. Now I'm wondering how to add new controllers to the Album module.

I create a new empty controller Named TestController and its view. In order to test it I changed module.config.php with the new TestController as default, and it works. After I changed again to the default Album Controller like in the tutorial.
And well.. the problem comes when in the add view, from the Album I changed this line

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url('test', array('action'=>'index'));?>">Test</a>
```

and I hit www.testing.loc/add in the browser but only renders a half of the script without any error.

Some of my module.config from the Album module looks like:

```
<?php
return array(
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController',
            'Album\Controller\Test' => 'Album\Controller\TestController',

        ),
    ),
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'album' => array(
                'type'    => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',

                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'     => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Album\Controller\Album',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),    
    'view_manager' => array(
        'template_path_stack' => array(
            'album' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Probably is a simply mistake with the parameters provided in the view for the url function, but I proved with others and it was the same. I'm starting with ZF2 but I can't figure out how to do use multiple controllers in the same module. Any advice is very welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no route named `test` inside your configuration. Syntax is:

```
$this->url('ROUTENAME', $routeParams);
```

Basically what you need to do is change the route:

```
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
        'test' => array(
            //copy the other parts
        )
    )
)
```

For further information see [Zend\Mvc\Router](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html)-Documentation